# How to render 0 for table export

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I want to include `0` also in the `exported` `table`, how to achieve this?

```
<input type="button" id="btnExport" value=" Export Table data into Excel " />
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="dvData">
    <table id="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Column One</th>
            <th>Column Two</th>
            <th>Column Three</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>098766655</td>
            <td>098869912</td>
            <td>096326991</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is a **Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/jWAJ7/4378/

Even I tried `tableexport.js plugin` which also failed to render `0`. I initialize it like so

```
$('#table').tableExport({ type: 'excel', escape: 'false' });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't have any relation with the plugins you're using but directly with the excel it self that remove the `left-zero's` from numbers in his columns.

Even if you try to add the '0' manually in the exported excel you could notice that it will be removed automatically.

You've to wrap them inside a quotes if you don't want them to be treated as numbers, see the example in this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jWAJ7/4380/)** :

```
<tr>
  <td>"098766655"</td>
  <td>"098869912"</td>
  <td>"096326991"</td>
</tr>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this what i wanted to know why it is not rendering `0`,  Good Explanation Thanks Alot !!:)